# How can i get access to the account name and not the account address in metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, react

[image]

Instead of the account address like shown here, how can i get the account name instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to know there is no name in accounts at ethereum. You can only access the address on ethereum, which is a 20 bytes string.